# concatenate numpy columns in different positions

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `x = np.empty([2,3])`. Assume I have two set of logical indices `indx1` and `indx2` and each one of them is paired with different columns, `set1` and `set2`:

```
 indx1 = [False,False,True]
 set1 = np.array([[-1],[-1]])
 indx2 = [True,True,False]
 set2 = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])
 #need to join these two writing operations to a one.
 x[:,indx1] = set1
 x[:,indx2] = set2
 >>> x
array([[1., 2., -1.],
       [1., 2., -1.]])
```

How can I use `indx1` and `indx2` at the same time? For instance, I am looking for something like this (which does not work):

```
x[:,[indx1,indx2]] = [set1,set2]
```

Comment: Why do you need this? How do you obtain the indices and the sets? If those have been obtained from an array with the same shape as x, maybe there is a way without using some intermediate index/set variables

Comment: @Tawy well if you use `PyTable`, performing `x[:indx1] = set1` and then `x[:,indx2] = set2` would take double the time of doing it at once. `indx1.size=indx2.size=...=indxj.size` and all of them are one dimensional. `set1.shape[0]=set2.shape[0]=...=setj.shape[0]`, however, they have different `shape[1]`. In other words, `setj` has the same number of rows but different number of columns

Comment: Ok, but how do you obtain the indices and the sets? I suppose they have been built with specific constraints. Otherwise, for instance, what do you expect to happen if there is a `True` at the same place in indx1 and indx2 ?

Comment: @Tawy Oh I see the confusion. It won't. The index arrays won't intersect. A column `i` is set to `True` in an only one logical index array

Comment: I suspect the double assignment is best, or at least competitive with alternatives.  `np.where` can work if `index2=~index1`, but then `set1` and `set2` must both have 3 columns.  I assume in a general case `index1` could be `[True, False, True,True,False], with no sorting or order, and 3 columns for 1 and 2 coumns for 2.

Comment: @hpaulj `index1` length cannot exceed the number of columns of `x`. It has to equal the number of columns of `x`. Your assumption about no order or sorting is right. The number of columns of `set`'s must equal the number of `True` occurences in the corresponding 'index' array. Note that it may have multiple `index`'s and `set`'s arrays, and not only two.

Comment: Since the `sets` will differ in length, it will be impossible to perform a pure multidimensional array operation.  One way or other you will iterate on those sets, even if it is to pad them to the common length.  I still think iterating on the index/set pairs is simplest.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there are array, which have different dimensions (**axis=0** if there the same dimension, and **axis=1** if there is different dimensions)

For the easiest concatenate:

```
import numpy as np

set1 = np.array([[3],[3]])
set2 = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])

indx1 = [False,False,True]
indx2 = [True,True,False]

sets = np.concatenate((set1, set2), axis=1)
np.concatenate((indx1, indx2), axis=0)

sets.sort()
```

output sets:

[image]

output index:

[image]

---

If you wan't to correlate sets with index - provide the proper output.

Comment: see the edit of what my expectation of the value of `x`.

Comment: I added - the result, which You need - however I suppose that it should have specific conditions

Comment: Right. this work assuming the columns elements are inorder. I changed my example so that your solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I did not manage to find an exact solution to the problem, but maybe (depending on how you generate the sets and indices), this will lead you in the right direction.

Let's suppose that, instead of the sparse definition of `set1` and `set2`, you have dense arrays, each with the same size as x:

```
indx1 = [False,False,True]
indx2 = [True,True,False]
fullset1 = np.array([[0, 0, -1],
                     [0, 0, -1]])
fullset2 = np.array([[1, 2, 0],
                     [1, 2, 0]])

x = np.select( [indx1, indx2], [fullset1, fullset2] )
print(x)
#[[1 2 -1]
# [1 2 -1]]
```

It works with one command and can be easily extended if you have indx3, indx4, etc. However, I see several drawbacks. First, it creates a new variable that satisfies the conditions, which may not be your use case. Also, if there is an index that is set to false for all indx variables, the result might be unexpected:

```
indx1 = [False,False,True,False]
indx2 = [True,True,False,False]
fullset1 = np.array([[0, 0, -1, 0],
                     [0, 0, -1, 0]])
fullset2 = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
                     [1, 2, 0, 0]])

x = np.select( [indx1, indx2], [fullset1, fullset2], default=None )
print(x)
#[[1 2 -1 None]
# [1 2 -1 None]]
```

In that case, my proposal (but I haven't tested the performances) would be to use an intermediate variable and `np.where` to fill the final variable:

```
x = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14], 
              [15, 16, 17, 18]])
#....
intermediate_x = np.select( [indx1, indx2], [fullset1, fullset2], default=None )

indx_final = np.where(intermediate_x == None)
x[indx_final] = intermediate_x[indx_final]
print(x)
#[[ 1  2 -1 14]
# [ 1  2 -1 18]]
```